# Como tranformar um array de floats para array de inteiros?

Tags: c

Como é que eu converto um array de floats para um array de inteiros?

Ex:

```
float grade{12.30, 15.55, 16.25, 0.00, 3.68}
```

Output: `{12, 15, 16, 0, 3}`

Comment: Você quer converter na declaração, na exibição, criar um novo array ou o que? Tem muitas interpretações possíveis para sua questão, seria bom delimitar melhor o que quer obter. Lembre-se que você pode [edit] seu post para dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Explique melhor clicando em [edit], na sua postagem. Comentários são efêmeros (e muitas vezes não lidos), o que importa para a resolução do problema deve fazer parte da pergunta original, com o máximo de detalhes possível para que você possa obter uma resposta que realmente faça o que você espera.

Comment: – Implement a function void  frequencies(float *grades,  int n, int *freq) that  receives the address of and array grades with the students’ exam grades (a float value between 0.0  and  20.0), the number of elements  in that array (n), and the  address  of  a  second  array
(freq) to be  filled with the absolute  frequency of  the integer part of  the grades stored in  the 
array grades. Use pointer arithmetic to solve this exercise.

Comment: Example:
• the array grades with content {8.23, 12.25, 16.45, 12.45, 10.05, 6.45, 14.45, 0.0, 12.67, 16.23, 18.75}  should produce a freq array with {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0}

Comment: Adicione essa informação traduzida à pergunta, para que seja claro para todos o objetivo

Answer (score 4):

Para converter float para int, é só usar o cast.

ficaria assim:

```
 int main() {

    float grade[5] = {12.30, 15.55, 16.25, 0.00, 3.68};
    int gradenew[5], i;


    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       gradenew[i] =  (int)(grade[i]);
    }

    printf("position[0]: %d",gradenew[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

note que a posição que eu imprimi já esta em inteiro, ou seja, 
você tem uma novo array de inteiros.

Saída:

```
position[0]: 12
```

Comment: Lembrando que o `cast` para `int` trunca a parte flutuante. Em determinados casos, é desejável que o `float` seja arredondado para cima, é o caso de `3.68` e `15.55`, que no caso foram arredondados para um inteiro "mais longe".

Comment: @Lacobus Embora o desejável/comum seja de fato arredondar na conversão de `float` para `int` o output mostrado na pergunta sugere truncar. Por isso eu diria que está de acordo com a pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco Concordo que a pergunta não está de todo clara, e eu não votei para reabrir a mesma. Estava apenas a sugerir que a resposta dá o *output* esperado de acordo com pergunta, ainda que não esteja clara. Logo estava apenas a contrapor o que o Lacobus tinha dito (que deveria ser arrendondado ao invés de truncado).

Comment: @Isac claro, acho válida a sua observação. Só mencionei pq os comentários na pergunta às vezes passam despercebidos (e mudam a situação toda), mas depois notei que você comentou ao final, sugerindo o autor a atualizar a pergunta.